# Is there a way to solve these questions by using logarithm and without calculator?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

$$2^{x+2} + 2^{x-1} + 2^x = 44$$

- Find the unknown $x$.

Indeed, I'm able to solve this question. However, there was something which they were doing the calculations by using logarithm. According to my views, it requires a calculator which we've to calculate with. Unfortunalety, we're not allowed to use calculator during the exam. Is there a way to solve these questions by using logarithm and without calculator?

My Kindest Regards!

Comment: Write $y=2^x $.

Comment: Hint: $2^{x+2} = 2(2^{x+1}) $

Comment: So, does log requires calculator?

Comment: @Enzo Taking logarithms does not require a calculator.  You can either leave an answer simplified with a logarithm (for example $\log_2(3)$ would be a completely reasonable solution [though not to this problem]), or if the expression is straight-forward enough, you can simplify the log to something nicer (in this problem, the solution is $\log_2(8)$, which simplifies to $3$, as $8 = 2^3$).

Comment: @Enzo Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it is $$2^x\left(4+\frac{1}{2}+1\right)=44$$

Answer (score 0):

If calculator is not required, then it needs to be easy to solve, with integer numbers. Try with $x=1,2,3$
$32 + 8 + 4 $

$x=3$

$2^5 + 2^2 + 2^3$

Comment: Have you solved it with log?

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested by several people, the first simplification to make is to factor $2^x$ out of each term.  This leave you with
$$ 2^{x+2} + 2^{x-1} + 2^x = 2^x \left( 2^2 + 2^{-1} + 1 \right) = 2^x \left( 4 + \frac{1}{2} + 1 \right) = 2^x \cdot \frac{11}{2} = 44. $$
We can then cancel the $\frac{11}{2}$ in order to isolate the $2^x$ (which is the most complicated looking part of the equation at this point), which gives us
$$ 2^x = 44\cdot \frac{2}{11} = 4\cdot 2 = 8.$$
Taking logarithms, we finally obtain
$$ x = \log_2(2^x) = \log_2(8) = \log_2(2^3) = 3.$$

Comment: Can't we use log at begin?

Comment: @Enzo In what way?

Comment: So we should use it at final, shouldn't we?

Comment: @Enzo There is no "ought to."  If a technique works, great!  I just don't see how taking logs without simplifying first is going to get us to a solution.  But my lack of vision doesn't imply that there is no such technique.

Comment: Which is more useful? taking logs or simpiflying?

Comment: @Enzo  Which is more useful depends entirely on what problem you are trying to solve.  In this problem, taking logs right off the bat is not going to give you a solution very easily.  So, try to make the expressions look simpler, then try again.

Comment: @Enzo Taking logarithms at the beginning doesn't change much. You have a sum of different numbers, and the logarithm doesn't know what to do with sums. So you have to factor out $2^x$ before you can do anything with the logarithm anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by $2^x$ and rewrite it as:
$$2^{x+2} + 2^{x-1} + 2^x = 2^x\left(2^2+2^{-1}+1\right)=44$$
$$2^x\cdot\frac{11}2=44$$
$$2^x=\frac{44\cdot2}{11}=8$$
$$2^x=2^3$$
Then you can get the logarithm of both LHS and RHS and you get:
$$\log_22^x=\log_22^3\rightarrow\color{red}{x=3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Were going to use the property of exponents $$2^{m+n}=2^m \cdot 2^n$$

The given equation, is this equivalent to $$2^x(4+\frac 12 +1)=44$$

$$\implies 2^x \times \frac{11}{2} =44 \implies 2^x =8$$

Since $8=2^3$ write $2^x=2^3$ and take $\log$ to the base $2$, giving $x=3$

Answer (score 0):

By inspection (trial and error) $x=3$ is a solution. Since the LHS is strictly increasing it is unique.